# How to get data between two dates where the date column is varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with a `MessageTimestamp` column of type `varchar(50)` instead of `datetime`. I would like to get data from this table between two dates.

Normally, if the column was `datetime`, I would use a query like:

```
select * 
from myTable
where MessageTimestamp >= @firstDate and MessageTimestamp <= @lastDate
```

However, I cannot use this right now since this is `varchar`. I need a way as easy as possible to get those data rather than updating the column type. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit: example date format stored -> 2016-05-16 11:20:00 AM

Comment: you need to post the format in which the date is stored

Comment: I edited the question by adding the format.

Comment: You need to use Convert() to convert your varchar to a datetime

Comment: Why are you using the wrong data type? This is like asking how to clean the floor with a toothbrush rather than buying a mop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CONVERT or CAST function. CONVERT(datetime, MesssageTimestamp) for example.

Comment: Based on the previous answer you need to convert the column convert(datetime, MessageTimestamp) >= @firstdate

Comment: That is correct I updated my answer. It's the column containing the varchar data that needs to be converted in order to be compared to time data types.

Comment: Thanks this is working, just one thing, for another table I see the date is saved as "19/05/2016 11:52:03 AM" and casting is not working for it. Any suggestion?

Comment: just a note: convert(datetime,@date,103) worked for the other. thanks

Comment: @ErayBalkanli it should work with convert. `SELECT convert(datetime, '19/05/2016 11:52:03 AM', 103)`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below code.

```
    Select * from myTable
     where cast(MessageTimestamp as datetime )>= @firstDate and cast(MessageTimestamp as datetime) <= @lastDate
```